# Changing CSS of one element when it's hovering another

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed position navbar with white links and I'm trying to make the links turn to black when they're above ("hovering") another element with a white background.

Navbar links CSS:

```
nav ul li a {color:#ffffff;}
```

Navbar CSS:

```
nav {position:fixed;}
```

White div CSS:

```
div.white {background-color:#ffffff;}
```

Imagine this is the HTML:

```
<nav><ul><li><a>Link</a></li></ul></nav>
<!-- Imagine there's a hero image here -->
<div id="heroimage"></div>
<div class="white">
```

Since the navbar is fixed to the top, when you scroll the website, the navbar will eventually get on top ("hover") the white div and the links will become "invisible". I'm trying to find a way to make them turn to black only when they are on top of the white div.

Is this possible with JQuery? What functions am I looking for? I couldn't find an answer elsewhere...

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: Nice, Rory, thanks. What would your approach be?

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? SO is for helping diagnose and solve problems in code. Even seeing your current HTML and CSS would be a start

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of JQuery, just HTML and CSS. I tried Googling for it but I couldn't find the solution to this specific issue. I apologize if this is the kind of question that doesn't belong here.

Comment: This kind of question belongs here, but usually you are expected to have some code, and we help point out why your code isn't working and/or how to fix it. The site doesn't tend to serve well as a "code-writing service", if you will.

Comment: I think I'm not expressing myself well and for that I apologize once again. Please, I'm not asking you to write code but to point me, a begginner in JQuery, in the right direction and/or source to learn about this. Like which functions am I looking for etc. if I'm still wrong I am more than happy to delete this "I-won't-help-cause-its-a-waste-of-my-time" question.

Comment: @Luis - Your description is all well and good, and I think fairly descriptive. Post a working code sample so that someone can see the problem and help you solve it. It's hard to tell you what to do otherwise - it's all abstract.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066783/detect-when-a-position-fixed-element-crosses-over-another-element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, see if that is more what you were asking for. You will have to scroll to see the "NAVBAR" color change. Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

**Edit:**

So now that I understand what you meant.

Here's another Fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/u96xa39L/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="colorMeDifferent" class="blackbarwhitelinks">NAVBAR</div>

<div class="hugeDiv">No color change on overlap</div>

<div id="hoveroverme" class="hoverBar">When we over lap here, colors change</div>

<div class="hugeDiv">No color change on overlap</div>
```

**Jquery/Javascript**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var hoverElement = $("#hoveroverme");
  var elementsToChange = $("#colorMeDifferent");


  if ( Math.abs(hoverElement.offset().top - elementsToChange.offset().top)  <= hoverElement.height()) {
    elementsToChange[0].className = "whiteBarBlackLinks";       
  } else {
    elementsToChange[0].className = "blackbarwhitelinks";
  }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#colorMeDifferent {
  position: fixed;
}

.blackbarwhitelinks {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.whiteBarBlackLinks {
  background-color: white;
  color:black;
}

.hugeDiv {
  min-height: 650px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Almond. This is great except the function is triggered when the user hovers the other element. I'm trying to find a way so that my navbar "detects" it's above the white div and then it triggers the JQuery function to change its links' CSS.

Comment: Almond, I'm guessing the function `className()` is actually `toggleClass()`?

Comment: If you copy the HTML, the CSS, and the JavaScript you're using on your site into a new jsFiddle I can be of more help. I'm a lot better when I can see the issue. 

I wasn't expecting you to be able to just drop in the code and have it work. It was more of just guidance by example, if you will. Though I'm more than happy to help.

Comment: className is the pure JS property. If you want to use jQuery it would be...
$(elementsToChange).addClass("blackbarwhitelinks");
$(elementsToChange).removeClass("whiteBarBlackLinks");

I used the pure JS property because it replaces the entire class attribute on the object. Not a very good implementation if the element has more than one class, but useful in this case (mostly because I code lazily when I can).

Comment: You were very very helpful. To achieve the final result I had to tweak a little bit but your code was definitely a start point!

Comment: Not sure why you removed the marked as answer though.

Comment: I answered your question as it was stated. Its not correct for you to change the requirements of the answer. Pretty thankless.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. The answer I posted here is indeed the answer. Its a general answer that will help future users. It may not have worked dropped into your codebase as is, but that main point of SO is assist future users. They will not glean any benefit from your new code as opposed to mine. Though I am glad to hear you have solved your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

Almond's answer was of great help to use as a base. This was the final result:

**HTML**

```
<nav><ul><li><a id="link">Link</a></li></ul></nav>
<!-- Some more HTML -->
<div id="content"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content {background-color:#fff;}
.navwhite {color:#fff;}
.navblack {color:#000;}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('nav>ul>li>a').addClass("navwhite");
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var offsetDiv = $('div#content').offset().top;
    var offsetNav = $('#link').offset().top;

    if (offsetDiv <= offsetNav){
        $('nav>ul>li>a').removeClass("navwhite").addClass("navblack");
    }
    else {
        $('nav>ul>li>a').removeClass("navblack").addClass("navwhite");
    }
});
```