# Detect when a div with fixed position crosses over multiple elements and change color

Tags: jquery, html, css

A similar question has been asked before -> [Detect when a div with fixed position crosses over another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44572553/detect-when-a-div-with-fixed-position-crosses-over-another-element?rq=1)

but I was wondering how it can be applied to multiple .div-to-cross elements?
The answer provided by @Louys Patrice Bessette works well, but is restricted to one single .div-to-cross element. I assumed it would be possible to just simply create another .div-to-cross and the.fixed element would change its color, but it is not the case.

Thank you for your help!

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var fixed = $("div.fixed");
  
  var fixed_position = $("div.fixed").offset().top;
  var fixed_height = $("div.fixed").height();

  var toCross_position = $(".div-to-cross").offset().top;
  var toCross_height = $(".div-to-cross").height();

  if (fixed_position + fixed_height  < toCross_position) {
    fixed.removeClass('white');
  } else if (fixed_position > toCross_position + toCross_height) {
    fixed.removeClass('white');
  } else {
    fixed.addClass('white');
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vH;
}

.fixed{
  position:fixed;
  top:calc(50% - 50px);
  left:0;
  background-color:black;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
}
.white{
  background-color:white;
}
.div-to-cross{
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}

/* just for this demo */
.spacer{
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="div-to-cross"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="div-to-cross"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I apologize for this. I've added the code I need help with to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you a simpler version. But you can make it even better. I am using the same approach you have followed in your question. I am just additionally repeating the loop for all three divs.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var fixed = $("div.fixed");
  
  var fixed_position = $("div.fixed").offset().top;
  var fixed_height = $("div.fixed").height();
  
  var checkpos = function(id){
    var toCross_position = $("#" + id + ".div-to-cross").offset().top;
    var toCross_height = $("#" + id + ".div-to-cross").height();
    
    var fixedtgt = $("div.fixed[data-id='"+ id +"']");
    var color = $("#"+id).attr('data-color');
    if (fixed_position + fixed_height  < toCross_position) {
      fixedtgt.css({'background-color':'black','z-index':'0' });
    } else if (fixed_position > toCross_position + toCross_height) {
      fixedtgt.css({'background-color':'black','z-index':'0' });
    } else {
      fixedtgt.css({'background-color': color,'z-index':'1' });
    }
  }
  
  checkpos("divone");
  checkpos("divtwo");
  checkpos("divthree");
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vH;
}

.fixed{
  position:fixed;
  top:calc(50% - 50px);
  left:0;
  background-color:black;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
}
.div-to-cross{
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}

/* just for this demo */
.spacer{
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed" data-id="divone"></div>
<div class="fixed" data-id="divtwo"></div>
<div class="fixed" data-id="divthree"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="div-to-cross" id="divone" data-color="white"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="div-to-cross" id="divtwo" data-color="red"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="div-to-cross" id="divthree" data-color="yellow"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Kiran Dash, this is a clever way to go around the issue ;)! But as I understood, your suggestion uses different .fixed divs that change whenever they cross a .div-to-cross with a matching #id, right? I need a fixed social media bar in all the pages of a website to change from black to white whenever it crosses a section. Your suggestion would imply the creation of a new social media bar every time I want it to change color, resulting in dozens of layered social media bars. Is there a way I can use just a specific tag or id for the sections where I need the social media bar to change color?

Comment: Oh. Understood. I know the above can be made simpler. But instead of writing all these code by yourself, I would suggest that you use http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/ . I have used this before in the exact same situation for changing color of nav based on which div has scrolled into viewport.