# Show div display none to block after pass another div then use onclick to display none again

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show a fixed div for some popup ad when scroll and pass another div on the page, and then use onclick button to hide it again, and I want this to load one time per page so the visitor if gone to the top of page and scrolled to the div again it will not appear again .. and all this work on mobile screens only!!

I use #onthediv just as a bridge without content. I tried many codes but no success.I hope it is clear what I really need :)

```
<div id = "onthediv"></div>
<div id="mydiv" style="position: fixed; z-index:9999; left: 0px; top: 35%;">
    <button class="btn" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:999;" 
               onclick="document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display='none'">
       <img src="CloseBtn.png" width="40" height="38">
     </button>
     <!--popup image -->
</div>
```

css
    .mydiv { display: none;
    }

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydiv").hide(); //hide your div initially
    var topOfOthDiv = $("#onthediv").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
            $("#mydiv").show(200); //reached the desired point -- show div
        }
    });
});
```

tried also

```
 document.getElementById("target-id").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect when a div with fixed position crosses over another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44572553/detect-when-a-div-with-fixed-position-crosses-over-another-element)

Comment: @Tuneer no i think it didn't do what i mean as it work with the fixed div not with the other div and also i don't know how to insert .style none to block in this mentioned code as i'm not good in j-queries stuff as i just try by googling :/

Comment: @misorude i did it, please advice if there is more edits to do :)