# How to animate left side border in the table of content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have left side content and right side table of contents.

What I am doing is when the user scrolls the page then I have to animate the right table of the content red border. I tried the below code.

```js
function runOnScroll(element) {
  console.log(element);
};

const i = document.querySelectorAll(`.rightwrap li`);
i && window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  for (let t of i) {
    let e = t.querySelector(".rightwrap li"),
      n = window.pageYOffset + t.runOnScroll().top,
      a = window.pageYOffset + i.runOnScroll().top,
      o = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight / 2,
      s = o - n;
    s < 1 && (s = 0), e.style.height = s + "px", a < o ? i.classList.add("is-active") : i.classList.remove("is-active")
  }
})
```

```css
.mainWrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.leftWrap {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.rightwrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 50px;
}

.h-500 {
  height: 650px
}

.dashlineWrap {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.vc_row {
  height: 500px;
}

.rightwrap ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.rightwrap ul li::before {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.rightwrap ul li.active::before {
  background-color: red;
}

.rightwrap ul li a {
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
</section>
<section class="dashlineWrap">

  <div class="vc_row h-500" id="tableofcontent-2">
    <h4>Row 2</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="dashlineWrap">

  <div class="vc_row h-500" id="tableofcontent-3">
    <h4>Row 3</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</section>

</div>

<div class="rightwrap">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Row 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Row 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Row 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You will have to use some logic similar as the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44572553/detect-when-a-div-with-fixed-position-crosses-over-another-element/44573288#44573288) to apply the active class on the relevant element. --- You posted no JS code at all... So there is nothing more I can say.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, Right let me add my js here

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, I added my script to the question. The script I am using that is learned from the google. I need to improve that. I am getting the error in the console Uncaught TypeError: t.runOnScroll is not a function after scroll.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let rowLis = document.querySelectorAll(".rightwrap li");
    
    let section1 = document.getElementById("section1");
    let section2 = document.getElementById("section2");
    let section3 = document.getElementById("section3");
    
    let section1Y = section1.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let section2Y = section2.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let section3Y = section3.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    
    let point1 = section1Y;
    let point2 = section2Y - section1Y;
    let point3 = section3Y - section2Y;
        
    const markRow = () => {
        let section1Y = section1.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        let section2Y = section2.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        let section3Y = section3.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        
        if ((section1Y < 0) && (section1Y > -point2)) {
            rowLis[0].classList.add("active");
        }
        else rowLis[0].classList.remove("active");
        
        if ((section2Y < 0) && (section2Y > -point3)) {
            rowLis[1].classList.add("active");
        }
        else rowLis[1].classList.remove("active");
        
        if ((section3Y < 0)) {
            rowLis[2].classList.add("active");
        }
        else rowLis[2].classList.remove("active");
    }
    
    document.addEventListener("scroll", markRow);
```

```css
.mainWrapper{display: flex;}
.leftWrap{width: 600px;margin: auto;border: 1px solid #222;}
.rightwrap{position: fixed;top: 0;right: 50px;}

.h-500{height:650px}
.dashlineWrap{background-color: #f9f9f9;}

/*.vc_row{height: 500px;}*/

.rightwrap ul li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.rightwrap ul li::before {

    content: '';
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
  

}
.rightwrap ul li.active::before {
    background-color: red;
}

.rightwrap ul li a {
    padding-left: 15px;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainWrapper">
    <div class="leftWrap">
        <section class="dashlineWrap" id="section1">       
            <div class="vc_row" id="tableofcontent-1">
                <h4>Row 1</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    
        <section class="dashlineWrap" id="section2">        
            <div class="vc_row" id="tableofcontent-2">
                <h4>Row 2</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    
        <section class="dashlineWrap" id="section3">        
            <div class="vc_row" id="tableofcontent-3">
                <h4>Row 3</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="rightwrap">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Row 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Row 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Row 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Let me check the answer

Comment: The demo now works with these current section lengths. I need a minute to improve it.

Comment: @Azu,  Thanks for the answer, I am getting the content dynamically. As there are more chances for increasing the content or less the content. You have statically defined the length -30 and -500. There is the possibility to increase the number of rows on left side and right side.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm changing now. Can I add `id`s to the `section` tags?

Comment: @Azu, I have added the same script in the question that I was trying.  Yes, you can add the ids to the section

Comment: I've added `id`s to the sections. The logic of the javascript is this: I get the Y coordinate of each section. Then I calculate the breakpoints for the `if` statements. In this way every section could have a different height.