# Check when a div with sticky element hovers over another elements and change it's image

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a function, that will detect a sticky element if it hovers over a certain element, and when it does it will change the image.
The problem I'm facing is that, I don't know how to check for second element if it hovers, because the first IF statment is always true, so the image won't change.

I found this issue: [Detect when a div with fixed position crosses over another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44572553/detect-when-a-div-with-fixed-position-crosses-over-another-element)

The code works fine, If I had just one element to cross over, but since I will have 6 elements, the code has to work for more than 1 element to cross over.

Can you help me out with this? Codepen -> https://codepen.io/rok-fullstack/pen/bGoyGwM

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var fixed = $(".img-frame");
  var img = $(".img-frame img");

  var fixed_position = $(".img-frame").offset().top;
  var fixed_height = $(".img-frame").height();

  var toCross_position = $(".section1").offset().top;
  var toCross_height = $(".section1").height();

  var toCross_position2 = $(".section2").offset().top;
  var toCross_height2 = $(".section2").height();

  var toCross_position3 = $(".section3").offset().top;
  var toCross_height3 = $(".section3").height();

  console.log("-------------------------")
  console.log("fixed_position", fixed_position)
  console.log("fixed_height", fixed_height)
  console.log("toCross_position2", toCross_position2)
  console.log("toCross_height2", toCross_height2)
  console.log("toCross_position3", toCross_position3)
  console.log("toCross_height3", toCross_height3)

  if (fixed_position + fixed_height > toCross_position2) {
    img.attr('src', 'https://golob.aklih.eu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Rdeča-sijaj-1.jpg')
  } else if (fixed_position < toCross_position2 + toCross_height2) {
    img.attr('src', 'https://golob.aklih.eu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Stresniki_Golob_prestiz_skrilat_briljant.jpg')
  } else if (fixed_position + fixed_height + toCross_height2 > toCross_position3) {
    console.log("sect3")
    img.attr('src', 'https://golob.aklih.eu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Stresniki_Golob_prestiz_skrilat_briljant.jpg')
  } else if (fixed_position < toCross_position3 + toCross_height2) {
    console.log("nomore 3")
    img.attr('src', 'https://golob.aklih.eu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Stresniki_Golob_prestiz_skrilat_briljant.jpg')
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 500vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.container,
.col,
.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
}

.col-1,
.col-2 {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.img-frame {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img-frame">
      <img src="https://golob.aklih.eu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Stresniki_Golob_prestiz_skrilat_briljant.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section section1">
      <div class="col-1"></div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <div class="small-text">Dež</div>
        <div class="heading">Neurja z močnimi nalivi</div>
        <div class="description">
          Sistem strešnih elementov Golob omogoča izdelavo strehe, ki tudi pri zahtevnejših konstrukcijah strehe zagotavlja zaščito pred vlago in dežjem. Dovršena oblika strešnikov vam zagotavlja vodotesnost tudi ob močnejših nalivih.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section section2">
      <div class="col-1"></div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <div class="small-text">Dež</div>
        <div class="heading">Neurja z močnimi nalivi</div>
        <div class="description">
          Sistem strešnih elementov Golob omogoča izdelavo strehe, ki tudi pri zahtevnejših konstrukcijah strehe zagotavlja zaščito pred vlago in dežjem. Dovršena oblika strešnikov vam zagotavlja vodotesnost tudi ob močnejših nalivih.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section section3">
      <div class="col-1"></div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <div class="small-text">Dež</div>
        <div class="heading">Neurja z močnimi nalivi</div>
        <div class="description">
          Sistem strešnih elementov Golob omogoča izdelavo strehe, ki tudi pri zahtevnejših konstrukcijah strehe zagotavlja zaščito pred vlago in dežjem. Dovršena oblika strešnikov vam zagotavlja vodotesnost tudi ob močnejših nalivih.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The second answer in your linked question seems to answer what you are looking for. Just replace ```$('.div-to-cross')``` with ```$('.section')```.

Comment: @Lalalena Thanks for your answer, but if you can take a closer look to my code, at the bottom I've selected all of my sections with `$('section1'),$('section2')`... Because I will have 6 different images for each element, that the div with a sticky element will cross. Or maybe I just don't get it? :)

Comment: Maybe you can add a minimal reproducible example or codepen?

Comment: @Lalalena I've added the codepen link -> https://codepen.io/rok-fullstack/pen/bGoyGwM

Comment: I suspect you'd have better luck using [the Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), rather than handling the `scroll` event and trying to work it out yourself.